# Using Git to clone or pull a depo into DesktopServer

Tags: wordpress, git, xampp

After doing some research on the Interweb I decided to give the free version of DesktopServer a try for my WordPress site development on my PC because of the wp-cli and Git intergration. During the installation DesktopServer automatically created a Wordpress site (no version control yet).

My question is: Could I use git clone or git pull to clone/pull a remote depo into my existing local WP site on DesktopServer?

Comment: Do you want to get rid of the existing WP site?

Comment: Yes, it's just an empty WP site set up by DesktopServer.

Comment: Then I'd think it was possible. Init git repo in the local WP site folder, add the remote, fetch, reset the head to be origin/master?

Comment: Sounds like a sound idea; I actually tried something else and it worked too.

Comment: I have done similar type of thing, but my repo is only store the wp-content folder which I pull / clone after I install the wordpress using wp-cli. I have written a shell script that will do all these set of instructions.

Comment: Everything seems to work, except for the login authentication...it keeps sending a warning about not able to modify header information...sometimes it complains about the password being incorrect, and sometimes I just see a bunch of warnings. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'll have to give evolutionxbox's suggestion a try some other time, but in the meantime I actually just cloned the repo to a folder under the "websites" directory, deleted the folder created by DesktopServer during setup, but kept and moved the wp-config file to the new folder. After renaming the new folder to the deleted folder. I got a working clone.